# How to let a non 'Administrator' user define a GPO in a Samba DC

Tags: group-policy, samba, domain-controller

I tried several times unsuccessfully to define a GPO in my Samba DC through RSAT "Group Policy Management" using the administrator account "adam1". "adam1" is a member of groups: `Administrators`, `Domain Admins`, `Domain Users`, `Enterprise Admins`, `G.P. Creator Owners` and `Schema Admins`.

If I define the GPO using the "Administrator" account it works. Meaning that the policy is spread to other computers in the domain and executed correctly. (The simplest thing, a message at login).

I would prefer to give a particular administrator the ability to define GPO(s) and leave alone the generic administrator 'Administrator' as much as possible.

After trying to define a GPO using the account 'adam1', by `dc1 $> journalctl -u samba-ad-dc.service` I see:

```
 dc1 winbindd[30459]: [2020/12/05 17:08:07.569375,  0] ../lib/util/util_runcmd.c:327(samba_runcmd_io_handler)
 dc1 winbindd[30459]:   /usr/sbin/samba-gpupdate:     apply_gp(lp, creds, test_ldb, logger, store, gp_extensions)
 dc1 winbindd[30459]: [2020/12/05 17:08:07.569383,  0] ../lib/util/util_runcmd.c:327(samba_runcmd_io_handler)
 dc1 winbindd[30459]:   /usr/sbin/samba-gpupdate:   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/samba/gpclass.py", line 4
 dc1 winbindd[30459]: [2020/12/05 17:08:07.569401,  0] ../lib/util/util_runcmd.c:327(samba_runcmd_io_handler)
 dc1 winbindd[30459]:   /usr/sbin/samba-gpupdate:     for gpo_obj in gpos:
 dc1 winbindd[30459]: [2020/12/05 17:08:07.569409,  0] ../lib/util/util_runcmd.c:327(samba_runcmd_io_handler)
 dc1 winbindd[30459]:   /usr/sbin/samba-gpupdate: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

I Installed Samba through packages in Debian 10.5 and configured it  following the Samba Wiki.